# Adding a Node + Typescipt Backend to angular app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, file

I am working on an angular project in which I need to read data automatically from a text file located in my desktop ( backend ) and manipulate it so that it appears in structured tables in the front end. My problem is that I don't know how to:
add node in the backend of my angular project.
Add all the dependencies that will help me read the text file.
Read the text file line by line and store the lines in json file.
Use the data structured in the json file to generate tables in html file
Also, can I read and manipulate data from text file without using json file.
Please note that I don't want to upload the text file from the front end ( where the client uploads the file by clicking on choose file ). The file I need is already in the desktop and I need to read its data in the server side.

Comment: Welcome to SO, when you ask a question, you should also share your efforts. It seems like you have not tried to google this. Let me help you with that . https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_enIN801IN801&ei=CAPaXY6HFdHTwALuv6nQAg&q=using+node+js+with+angular&oq=using+node+js+with+angular&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.7176.7176..7684...0.2..0.0.0.......0....1..gws-wiz.qY42EFuRmKo&ved=0ahUKEwiOq5jG_YHmAhXRKVAKHe5fCioQ4dUDCAs&uact=5

Comment: This question will be closed because of this reason. If you are planning to ask more question, please share your efforts and code.